# First method after touching a table view cell didSelectRowAtIndexPath or prepareforSegue?

Tags: ios

I have designed a table view of various books in sections according to their type.If user touches on cell ,a segue is performed to a new view controller which needs a book item.I have initialised this book in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method.But after a touched is  method is not called first,the following method is called first!!!!

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

What is is the first method called after touching a table view cell....?

Comment: Why don't you check it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to link segue not with cell but with view of the current view controller. In such case when you click on cell

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

will not be called.
Then in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can manualy perform segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySequeIdentifier" sender:self];
```