# Segue to a UINavigation Controller programmatically without storyboards

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have code that uses Storyboards for seques, like so:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDiagnosis"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHappiness:self.diagnosis];
    }
    ...
```

But I want to do it programmatically. I have myViewController class and when I click on a button I want to animate and push to myUINavigationController.

How is this done programmatically?

Comment: Perhaps answer on your question you can find in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711668/first-method-after-touching-a-table-view-cell-didselectrowatindexpath-or-prepare/18711785#18711785

Comment: self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller... animated:YES

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `segue` can be used only with if you have a `UINavigationController` that will handle the navigation (push, pop, etc).

So if you have a `UINavigationController` and you want to push another `UIViewController` on the stack without using `segue` then you can use `pushViewController:animated:` method which also has a reverse `popViewControllerAnimated:`. Also `UINavigationController` provides other methods for adding/removing `UIVIewControllers`, for more info check [UINavigationController class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:)

Comment: How do I make my starting app viewcontroller slide to a navigation controller? Like I want a starting page with no toolbar, then a user clicks register and it animates to a register view with back button.

Comment: Take a look at documentation about presenting modal view controllers. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Answer (score 10):

First things first, a segue cannot be created programmatically. It is created by the storyboard runtime when it is time to perform. However you may trigger a segue, which is already defined in the interface builder, by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Other than this, you can provide transitions between view controllers without segue objects, for sure. In the corresponding action method, create your view controller instance, either by allocating programmatically or instantiating from storyboard with its identifier. Then, push it to your navigation controller.

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"my-vc-identifier"];
    // OR MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    // any setup code for *vc

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```