# Swift: Passing Variable between Views not updating first time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with cell data. When I click the cell, it takes me to another view controller and displays the cell label in a UIlabel on the new ViewController.

However, When I go back to the tableview and select a different cell, the value on the new view controller doesn't update immediately. It displays the last clicked cell, then if I go back and repeat the process a second time it will update.

## didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    self.labeltosend = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
}
```

## prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == PostSegueIdentifier {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NewViewController {
            destination.newlabel = labeltosend
        }
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to reload the data somehow?

## edit 1: Destination View Controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var dispLabel: UILabel!
var newlabel = String()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    dispLabel.text = newlabel
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.

}
```

Comment: What is PostSegueIdentifier?

Comment: A variable with the segue identifier name

Comment: I assumed to create the segue you control-dragged from the table view to the other view controller?

Comment: yup, and then chose the identifier name (PostSegueIdentifier)

Comment: How are you getting back to the first view controller? What kind of segue is it? Usually when you return to view controller from on that has been segued to that view controller is then released. So it is very odd that it would displaying a value that has been passed to it previously as it should have just been instantiated. Is that the entirety of the DestinationViewController class?

Comment: my project started with a tableviewcontroller - I then dragged a new view onto the storyboard, created the class, dragged from the tableviewcell to the view, created the segue identifier and then the new view automatically had a previous button top left.

Answer (score 2):

`prepareForSegue(_:sender)` is not called if you draw `segue` from cell to next view controller. Try to draw segue from view controller to view controller. And perform a manual segue using  `performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegueIdentifier" sender:self)` in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)`. For more info please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711668/first-method-after-touching-a-table-view-cell-didselectrowatindexpath-or-prepare).

Answer (score 1):

Think prepareForSegue is sometimes getting called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can move that code to prepareForSegue. When you set up a segue as you have sender in prepareForSegue is the indexPath of row tap, precisely so you can do these sorts of things.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == PostSegueIdentifier {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? NewViewController {
            let indexPath = sender as NSIndexPath
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

            self.labeltosend = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
            destination.newlabel = labeltosend
        }
    }
}
```

You should read Duncan's comment.

Answer (score 1):

First: if you have your segue connected from the UITableViewCell, don't. Delete it and connect the segue from the view controller itself.

Second: on the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, call `prepareForSegue` method.

And finally on the destination controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dispLabel: UILabel!
var newlabel = String()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //dispLabel.text = newlabel
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    dispLabel.text = newlabel

}
```

Also, you need to improve your naming convention. Is really confusing

Hope this helps!